# When will the progress report (public preview) fetaure will be released for cloud version?

Tags: testing

On the release note of August 12, it is mentionned that this feature will be released in 2 ou 3 weeks. But today I still dont'see it. Having delays ?
Thanks a lot
M

Answer (score 0):

It appeared last week on Thursday 26th August